# Using setEditing does not get the tableview to go into edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have used the following code (extract) in one tableview and works well however I can't get the same code to work in a second tableview: What I need to do is be able to move rows in the table.

```
@IBOutlet weak var reOrgApps: UIBarButtonItem!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.reOrgApps.action = #selector(self.reOrgApps(_:))
    self.reOrgApps.title = "ReOrg"
    self.setEditing(isEditingMode, animated: true)}

@IBAction func reOrgApps(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if isEditingMode
    {
        isEditingMode = false
        self.reOrgApps.title = "ReOrg"
        self.tableView.isEditing = false
    }
    else
    {
        isEditingMode = true
        self.reOrgApps.title = "Done"
        self.tableView.isEditing = true
    }
    self.setEditing(isEditingMode, animated: true)
}
```

The button work as expected but the tableview does not go into edit mode
I have used the exact code in a different tableview and it work fine.

So I am missing something that I can't work out. Any help gratefully accepted
I know there have been similar questions and I have tried the various answers with no success.

Comment: `self.setEditing`, `tableView.setEditing`, `tableView.isEditing` and `isEditingMode` is a bit confusing 

Comment: Agree - I actually had removed tableView.setEditing - but not in the question code. now removed

Comment: Is this a table view controller or is this a view controller with a table view?

Comment: view controller with a tableview

Comment: I had internet problems now your comments and code have disappeared.

Comment: I found the problem, I tried to pass a variable to :

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, another: IndexPath)

Which was wrong and swift then simply ignored everything to do with  Editing. Removing the , another: IndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I tried to pass a variable to :

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, another: IndexPath)
```

Which was wrong and swift then simply ignored everything to do with Editing. Removing the , another: IndexPath.resolved the issue. 
Fundamental mistake overlooked in the rush to get the class done.